# Как использовать unique_ptr для хендлов

Tags: c++

У `std::unique_ptr` можно задать свой *deleter* - шаблонный параметр, который отвечает за удаление объекта. Это позволяет использовать `std::unique_ptr` не только для памяти выделенной с помощью `new`, но и для разного рода "хендлов" на объекты. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Зачем задавать вопрос и в тот же момент давать на него такой развернутый вопрос? Это перевод с SO?

Comment: @Arkady: Это FAQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Допустим у нас следующее API:

```
typedef unspecified_type* HANDLE; // указатель на какой-то тип
HANDLE CreateObject();
bool CloseHandle(HANDLE handle);
```

#### Вспомогательный класс

Мы можем написать свой класс-*deleter*:

```
struct HandleDeleter {
    void operator()(HANDLE handle) {
        ::CloseHandle(handle);
    }
};
```

И с его помощью сделать `typedef` для `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<
    std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type,
    HandleDeleter>;

UniqueHandle handle(CreateObject(123));
```

#### Лямбда-выражение

Если мы не хотим писать свой класс-"функтор", то его можно создать с помощью лямбда-выражения:

```
const auto handle_deleter = [](HANDLE handle){ CloseHandle(handle); };
using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<
    std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type,
    decltype(handle_deleter)>;

UniqueHandle handle(CreateObject(123), handle_deleter);
```

(Переменная `handle_deleter` определена как `const`, а значит она может быть в заголовочном файле.)

Проблема в том, что тип лямбда-выражения (объект-замыкание) не имеет конструктора по умолчанию, а значит мы должны передавать его в конструктор `std::unique_ptr`.

#### Указатель на функцию (простое решение)

Лямбда выражение выше просто вызывает `CloseHandle`, и мы вполне можем заменить его на указатель на функцию:

```
using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<
    std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type,
    decltype(&CloseHandle)>;

UniqueHandle handle(CreateObject(123), CloseHandle);
```

Проблема с конструктором остается - значение по умолчанию указателя на функцию - это `nullptr`, и нам надо инициализировать его указателем на саму `CloseHandle`.

## Указатель на функцию (хорошее решение)

Итак, нам надо взять указатель на функцию `CloseHandle`, и превратить его значение в тип. Для этого в стандартной библиотеке есть класс `std::integral_constant`, который принимает параметр шаблона не-тип, и имеет соответствующий оператор преобразования:

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
    ...
    constexpr operator T() { return v; }
};
```

Если мы используем его в качестве *deleter*, то он будет преобразовываться к указателю на `CloseHandle`:

```
using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<
    std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type,
    std::integral_constant<decltype(&CloseHandle), &CloseHandle>>;

UniqueHandle handle(CreateObject(123));
```

## Хендл не-указатель

Что делать если тип хендла - это не указатель? Например

```
typedef unsigned long HANDLE;
```

Тогда надо писать свой класс-deleter. `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` не использует `T*` напрямую, а вместо этого он должен использовать `Deleter::pointer` если такой тип есть. При этом тип `pointer` должен уметь сравниваться с `nullptr`, по этому мы должны сделать его классом:

```
struct HandleDeleter {
    struct pointer {
        pointer() {}
        pointer(std::nullptr_t) {}
        pointer(HANDLE handle) : value_(handle) {}

        operator HANDLE() { return value_; }

        friend bool operator==(pointer lhs, pointer rhs) { return lhs.value_ == rhs.value_; }
        friend bool operator!=(pointer lhs, pointer rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

        HANDLE value_ = 0;
    };

    void operator()(pointer p) {
        ::CloseHandle(p.value_);
    }
};

using UniqueHandle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, HandleDeleter>;

UniqueHandle handle(CreateObject(123));
```

`operator HANDLE()` нужен для того, чтобы мы могли писать `handle.get()` вместо `handle.get().value_`. Он же работает и как оператор приведения к `bool`.

Теоретически, если невалидное значение хендла отличается от нуля, мы можем написать

```
const HANDLE INVALID_HANDLE = -1;
...
HANDLE value_ = INVALID_HANDLE;
```

И согласно стандарту это будет работать, т.к. реализация `std::unique_ptr` должна везде использовать `if (p_ == nullptr)` вместо `if (p)`, в том числе и в реализации `unique_ptr::operator bool()`. Однако поведение кода может быть весьма не очевидно:

```
UniqueHandle empty;
assert(empty == nullptr); // OK, равно nullptr
assert(!empty); // OK, преобразуется в false
assert(empty.get() == nullptr); // OK, равно nullptr
assert(empty.get()); // O_o не равно нулю
```

Comment: А не проще ли написать простейший класс-обертку для хэндла? Зачем тут unique_ptr?