# Умные указатели и деструкторы

Tags: c++, c++11

В новом стандарте появились умные указатели, что же теперь писать в деструкторах?

Comment: то же, что и раньше. Но если раньше Вы в деструкторе только вызываели delete, значит что то не то делаете.

Comment: Текущий стандарт `c++14`. `c++17` на подходе. А умные указатели и в `c++03` были, например `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @alexolut, `auto_ptr` это полоумный указатель

Comment: @ixSci на тот момент возможности языка не позволяли сделать лучше. Но это не значит, что он не относится к категории `умных`.

Comment: @alexolut, всё они(возможности) позволяли. `auto_ptr` это выкидыш, который непонятно вообще зачем добавили.

Comment: в контексте 03 стандарта auto_ptr правильно нельзя было реализовать, так как нужна была move сементика.

Comment: @KoVadim, если нельзя было реализовать в точности так, как сейчас реализован `unique_ptr`, вовсе не означает, что нельзя было нормально реализовать «умный» указатель, с перемещающей семантикой.

Comment: В книге Майерса Эффективный и современный С++. 42 рекомендации по использованию C++11 и C++14  есть большая выкладка, почему нельзя было. Если кратко, то перемещающую сементику нельзя было сделать, потому что ее не было:)

Comment: @KoVadim, а где конкретно? Что-то я там не вижу. Вот Вам [пример](http://www.coderage.com/move_ptr/libs/move_ptr/doc/index.html). И это не единственный возможный дизайн, его можно было бы сделать и по-другому. Так что, чтобы там Майерс не утверждал, сделать было можно и нужно, но сделали так, как получилось.

Comment: вроде на 126 странице.

Comment: Да просто это был не интеллектуальный указатель, а попытка реализации семантики перемещения методами C++ того времени...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну теоретически теперь в деструкторах можно ничего не писать. В умных указателях можно задать функциональный объект, который отвечает за освобождение ресурсов. То есть можно не ограничиваться освобождением памяти. Используя умные указатели можно закрывать подключения к БД, открытые файлы, вызывать какие-нибудь функции типа `CloseHandle` из Win API.
Вот например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

//Представим что это какой-то ресурс, который нельзя просто создать или удалить
struct Res{
    std::string name;
    Res(const std::string &name):
        name(name)
    {}
};

//Функция для создания
Res* getRes(const std::string &name){
    std::cout << "Res{" << name << "} created" << std::endl;
    return new Res(name);
}

//Функция для удаления
void deleteRes(Res *res){
    std::cout << "Res{" << res->name << "} deleted" << std::endl;
    delete res;
}

int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<Res, void(*)(Res*)> pRes1(getRes("unique_ptr"), &deleteRes); //Res{unique_ptr} created
    std::shared_ptr<Res> pRes2(getRes("shared_ptr"), &deleteRes);                //Res{shared_ptr} created
                                                                                 //Res{shared_ptr} deleted
                                                                                 //Res{unique_ptr} deleted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы стали использовали объект определенного класса с умной обёрткой, то теперь не нужно вызывать `delete` для этого объекта.

Если у Вас была ситуация вида

```
class Foo {
    Bar* bar;

    Foo() {
        bar = new Bar();
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete bar;
    }
};
```

и Вы решили заменить `Bar*` на `std::shared_ptr<Bar>`, то деструктор `Foo` можно удалить или оставить пустым, так как умные указатели для того и созданы, чтобы при их уничтожении (что и происходит при удалении класса `Foo`, так как `bar` теперь не указатель, а самостоятельный объект другого класса) удалялся ресурс, которыми они владеют.

Comment: Я понимаю как использовать умные указатели, я хотел узнать, какие ещё реализации освобождения памяти могут присутствовать в деструкторе, не связанные с указателями

Comment: @Сергей, `CloseHandle`, `DbConnectionClose` и так далее

Comment: Буду читать. спасибо.

Comment: @ixSci при настройке кастомного удалятора их, кстати, тоже можно успешно использовать в составе смарт-поинтера.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно "правилу нуля" (Rule of Zero, [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), [Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-zero), [оригинальная статья](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)), деструктор надо писать только если класс отвечает за владение объектом. При этом согласно принципу одной ответственности ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) класс не должен отвечать ни за что другое.

Другими словами, если класс - это не умный указатель/хендл/etc, то ему не нужен деструктор.
При этом например умные хендлы зачастую можно сделать через `unique_ptr`, передав ему нужный deleter ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423359/177684)).

Разумеется, если нужен виртуальный или защищенный деструктор, то его надо объявить (при помощи `=default;`).